# d3.js small multiples map with different filled country for every multiple

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps

I've created a small multiples map with d3.js. Each multiple is a different country, which in my csv is labeled as an Exporter. I have 11 Exporter countries: Canada, Russia, USA, Italy, France, UK, Brazil, China, India, Germany, and Japan.

I would like to fill each country, but only if it is the country representing the multiple. So only one country is filled per multiple.

You can view my bl.ock here. The country (Exporter) of the multiple is where the lines converge: https://bl.ocks.org/JulienAssouline/f899e2d6927aea6be65a109854b6f88a

Right now I only have the US filled for every multiple. I filled it with this code:

```
svg.selectAll(".country")
            .data(countries)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "country")
            .attr("fill", function(d){
              if(d.properties.name == "United States"){
                return "red"
              } else {
                return "#eeedeb"
              }
            })
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("opacity", function(d){
              if(d.properties.name == "United States"){
                return 0.4
              } else {
                return 1
              }
            })
```

This is obviously wrong but I am not sure how to fill each Exporter country per multiple.

Here is all of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3: Loading TopoJSON data and generating SVG paths</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      /* No style rules here yet */
body,html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
  }

#chart{
    background-color: white;
    stroke-width: 1;
  } 

  .country{
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 0.1;
  }  



    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //Width and height
      var w = 450;
      var h = 800;

      var margin = {
          top: 10,
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 30
        };

        var width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
        var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;


      var lineScale = d3.scaleSqrt()
        .domain([0, 332])
        .range([0.5, 3])

      var circleScale = d3.scaleSqrt()
        .domain([0, 4445])
        .range([0.5, 10])



      // define map projection
      var projection = d3.geoAzimuthalEquidistant()
        .translate([w/2, h/2 - 150])
        .scale(100)
      //   .scale([500]);

      //Define default path generator
      var path = d3.geoPath()
        .projection(projection)


      // var svg = d3.select("body")
      //   .append("svg")
      //   .attr("id", "chart")
      //   .attr("width", w)
      //   .attr("height", h)
      //   .append("g")
      //   .attr("transform", "translate(0" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        d3.json("world.topojson", function(json){
          d3.csv("arms_transfer_2012_2016.csv", function(error, data){
            // data.forEach(function(d){
            //   d.Lon_Residence = +d.Lon_Residence
            //   d.Lat_Residence = +d.Lat_Residence
            // })
            var countries = topojson.feature(json, json.objects.countries).features

            var Exporters = d3.nest()
              .key(function(d){ return d.Exporter; })
              .entries(data)

              console.log(Exporters)

              var svg = d3.select("body")
                .selectAll("svg")
                .data(Exporters)
                .enter()
                .append("svg")
                .attr("id", "maps")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform",  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")


            svg.selectAll(".country")
            .data(countries)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "country")
            .attr("fill", function(d){
              if(d.properties.name == "United States"){
                return "red"
              } else {
                return "#eeedeb"
              }
            })
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("opacity", function(d){
              if(d.properties.name == "United States"){
                return 0.4
              } else {
                return 1
              }
            })



            svg.selectAll("circles")
              .data(function(d){ return d.values })
              .enter()
              .append("circle")
              .attr("class", "importer")
              .attr("r", function(d){
                return circleScale(d.Millions)
              })
              .attr("cx", function(d){
                var coords = projection([d.Longitude_imp, d.Latitude_imp])
                return coords[0];
              })
              .attr("cy", function(d){
                var coords = projection([d.Longitude_imp, d.Latitude_imp])
                return coords[1];
              })
              .style("fill", function(d){
                if(d.Millions > 20){
                  return "#cd0d0e"
                } else {
                  return "none"
                }
              })

            svg.selectAll(".arcs")
              .data(function(d){ return d.values})
              .enter()
              .append("path")
              .style("stroke", function(d){
                if(d.Millions > 20){
                  return "#cd0d0e"
                }
              })
              .attr("d", function(d){
                return lngLatToArc(d, 1)
              })
              .style("fill", "none")
              .style("opacity", 0.5)
              .style("stroke-width", "0.5px")

              svg.append("text")
                .attr("x", 100)
                .attr("y", 100)
                .text(function(d){
                  return d.Exporter
                })



          function lngLatToArc(d, bend){
                // If no bend is supplied, then do the plain square root
                bend = bend || 1;
                // `[d.Lon_Origin, d.Lat_Origin]` and `[d.Lon_Residence, d.Lat_Residence]` are arrays of `[lng, lat]`
                // Note, people often put these in lat then lng, but mathematically we want x then y which is `lng,lat`


                var sourceLngLat = [d.Longitude_exp, d.Latitude_exp],
                    targetLngLat = [d.Longitude_imp, d.Latitude_imp];



                if(targetLngLat && sourceLngLat){

                  var sourceXY = projection(sourceLngLat),
                      targetXY = projection(targetLngLat);

                  // Uncomment this for testing, useful to see if you have any null lng/lat values
                // if (!targetXY) console.log(d, targetLngLat, targetXY)
                var sourceX = sourceXY[0],
                    sourceY = sourceXY[1];

                  var targetX = targetXY[0],
                      targetY = targetXY[1];

                  var dx = targetX - sourceX,
                      dy = targetY - sourceY
                    dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) * bend;

                    // To avoid a whirlpool effect, make the bend direction consistent regardless of whether the source is east or west of the target
                var west_of_source = (targetX - sourceX) < 0;
                if (west_of_source) return "M" + targetX + "," + targetY + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + sourceX + "," + sourceY;
                return "M" + sourceX + "," + sourceY + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + targetX + "," + targetY;

                } else{
                  return "M0,0,l0,0z";
                }
              }

          })
        })


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My data along with the Topojson file I used can be found in my public gist here: https://gist.github.com/JulienAssouline/f899e2d6927aea6be65a109854b6f88a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing a parent's element's datum when entering child elements can be a challenge. However, there are a few ways to achieve this.

One method is to set a property of the parent element:

```
.property("exporter",function(d) { return d.key; });
```

This will set a property for each svg you append - as the datum key attribute is the country name, we can use this property to color countries when appending data:

```
.attr("fill", function(d) {
    if(d.properties.name == d3.select(this.parentNode).property("exporter")){
...
```

Alternatively, we can use d3.local(). Which incidentally, the [API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#local-variables) recommends for small multiples:

> D3 locals allow you to define local state independent of data. For
>   instance, when rendering small multiples of time-series data, you
>   might want the same x-scale for all charts but distinct y-scales to
>   compare the relative performance of each metric.

Though, it also states: "If you are just setting a single variable, consider using selection.property", which is the method presented above.

To follow the second approach you would declare a local variable:

```
var local = d3.local();
```

And set it like so when appending the svgs:

```
.each(function(d) { local.set(this, d.key); })
```

And then get it when coloring:

```
.attr("fill",function(d) {     
    if(d.properties.name == local.get(this)) {
      return "red";
    ...
```

[Here's](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/b8979ef31a691b6f9523774a7c8d6498) an updated block with the second approach (with the first approach in comments).

Comment: Good and complete answer, +1. But I beat you on the *"code golf"*.

Comment: Yep, you sure did, I thought about including it, but figured I'd have more fun with the property/local approaches.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, they (property/local) are way faster... hence my +1.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, I think I have to go do some testing.

Comment: Selecting and traversing the DOM are normally slow operations.

Comment: Ah yeah, wasn't thinking that too far down the road on that.

Comment: Awesome thank you both for your help! Hadn't heard about d3.local() before so I guess I've got some reading to do.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest alternative is just getting the datum of the parent element:

```
if(d.properties.name == d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().key)
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/dbda1acf2f76012ab557d7a24b1b7ecb/34b1273419327ce258309f9bf4522ea2aa186d92